# javascript code fix for multiple range slider inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I cant use multiple range sliders on a single page. All inputs change only the first output of the page.

the example is on the following link.

http://codepen.io/andreruffert/pen/jEOOYN

```js
$(function() {
  var output = document.querySelectorAll('output')[0];
  
  $(document).on('input', 'input[type="range"]', function(e) {
        output.innerHTML = e.target.value;
  });
  
  $('input[type=range]').rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

output {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--
  rangeslider.js example
  
  https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js
  by André Ruffert - @andreruffert
-->

<h2>Floating point boundaries</h2>
<input type="range" value="0.5" step="0.1" min="0.1" max="3.0">
<br>
<output>0.5</output>
<br>
<input type="range" value="0.5" step="0.1" min="0.1" max="3.0">
<br>
<output>0.5</output>
```

Comment: So wht is the problem?

Comment: When I use multiple inputs all sliders manipulate the output of the first input only. the other outputs dont work

Comment: I have updated the code. have a look at the results of the code please. the second input slider also changes the first output

Comment: cool. Let me look into it.Hope i can be of any help

Comment: The offending line is `var output = document.querySelectorAll('output')[0];` which says that only the first `<output>` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You have to identify your `inputs` and `outputs` so you can link them in some way. For example you could give an `id` to your `input` element, and give the output a `class` name matching the id of the related `input`. And with a simple selector you can target the proper `element` to modify. Like this:

```
<h2>Floating point boundaries</h2>
<input id="floating" type="range" value="0.5" step="0.1" min="0.1" max="3.0">
<br>
<output class="floating">0.5</output>
<h2>Other slider</h2>
<input id="other" type="range" value="0.5" step="0.1" min="0.1" max="3.0">
<br>
<output class="other">0.5</output>
```

then:

```
$(document).on('input', 'input[type="range"]', function(e) {

            document.querySelector('output.'+this.id).innerHTML = e.target.value;
      });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPajvp